# Devexpress disabled button column datagrid

Tags: angular, button, datagrid, devexpress, disabled-control

I defined a button inside a column of a datagrid. Is it possible to disable the button based on the happening of certain conditions? I have only managed to find the "visible" option which allows me to hide it but not disabling it.

```
<dx-data-grid id="gridContainer" [dataSource]="orders" [showBorders]="true">
 <dxi-column type="buttons>
          <dxi-button icon=".../image.png" [onClick]="updatePositive">
          </dxi-button>
    </dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

Comment: I think you are searching [this](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t666836/datagrid-how-to-enable-disable-a-button-that-resides-in-a-cell-template-based-on-a-value). In this ticket you can see how they use disable property. I hope this will help you

Comment: No it is not recognized "disabled" property in <dxi-button>